# RESTFUL routes in API

Tags: rest, twitter, routes

I know there are several resources out there explaining how to create RESTful routes. I have an api that looks up a twitter user by their ID and then can also post a tweet if their authorized to do so. In terms of routing

Should list all twitter_accounts in DB.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/twitter_accounts/
```

Should list all information pertaining to specific user.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/twitter_accounts/525538870
```

This is where I am confused because some resources suggest one thing while others suggest another.

Should this be the POST route for a tweet by a user?

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/twitter_accounts/525538870/tweet/
```

If not, would it just be

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tweet/
```

And the user id along with the tweet text is passed in as parameters?

Are both acceptable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any technical right or wrong way per se so ultimately it's up to you and what works best for your potential users. That being said, the second one seems a lot cleaner and more RESTful. It's also the format that Twitter uses. Here's the payload when you delete a tweet:

```
Request URL:https://twitter.com/i/tweet/destroy
Request Method:POST
```

UserId is passed via the body of the request.

Comment: thanks @ccnixon. I was leaning that way too based on the Twitter documentation. Thanks for the input!